# node.js and express: use more than one views directory

Tags: node.js, express

Using node.js 0.12.35 and Express 4.x.
Currently I have the need to access different locations for my views. so the API Documentation of Express 4.x says that the views property of the app.set method would take "A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array."
So please can you give me an example of how to define such an array? Everything I tried so far ended up in this error message.
I used the following style for my app.set

```
app.set('views', ['/my/path/components/views/' + 'base', '/my/path/components/views/' + 'starters']);
```

but it does not work. I get an error message:

```
TypeError: **Arguments to path.join must be strings**
    at path.js:360:15
```

So what am I missing? How can I add an array to app.set?
Actually I have tried to debug it on my own and had a look into the view.js script of express. From there I can see that the array is correctly passed to this script, I can see two different root paths, but from there it does not correctly constructs the full path to the different, in my case .jade files as I use the jade engine. That means the next path.join with the root path and the file itself does not work and throws the error. Digging deeper, it looks like path.join is not able to take arrays? But how should the multiple views path work then? I thought, that Express 4.x should be able to use multiple views, but how if the views.js that comes out of the box is not able to handle such arrays? I am lost...

Comment: You write _"I used the following style"_. Is that the _exact_ code you're using, though? Passing multiple view directories as an array works just fine for me ([example](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/f7ac08ff783ea591d89c)).

Comment: Thanks for the example. You are right, it works if everything is in the directory where the node.js script is started. But I need to start it from the outside of that directory. So if my app.js is sitting in /my/path/components/application I want to have directory /my/path/components/base and /my/path/components/starters for the views. And when  I try to do this, I fail.

Comment: That also works just fine for me (app.js in /tmp, view directories in /var/tmp, for instance). It sounds to me like you're programmatically building the path strings, perhaps something fails with that?

Comment: Ok, now I am really puzzled. Unfortunately I cleaned my system, because with your tipps, I thought I now know how to do it. But now also your test code does not work in my environment. So I think it is something about versions of node.js and express. So node.js I am running 0.12.4 and express 4.12.4 (I upgraded to this versions when your code was working before). So at the moment I am completely lost.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I now got it. It seems to be a version issue. After a npm install it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, and with the help of robertklep the answer is, that it was a version problem in the package.json.
It **does not work** with these dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"express": "~4.9.0",
"body-parser": "~1.8.1",
"cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
"morgan": "~1.3.0",
"serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
"debug": "~2.0.0",
"jade": "~1.6.0"
```

}

But it works good with these dependencies declared:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.12.4",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "morgan": "~1.5.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "jade": "~1.10.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set multiple folders to views. What you can do though is to set views to:

```
app.set('views', '/my/path/components/views/');
```

and then to render for example index.html from base folder use

```
res.render('base/index');
```

Even if the array you used worked you would need to tell express in which folder the view you want is, right? How would you do that if i may ask?

Comment: [The Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set) explicitly states that you _can_ set multiple view directories, and also how it will handle such configuration: _"If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array."_

Answer (score 0):

The feature of use more then one views folders are supported natively in Express >=4.10

You should pass an array of locations to the views property, like so:

```
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/oneViewFolder', __dirname + '/anotherViewFolder']);
```

In the early release of Express You should modify the lookup logic yourself so that it works the way you want, for example:

```
function enableMultipleViewFolders(express) {
// proxy function to the default view lookup
var lookupProxy = express.view.lookup;

express.view.lookup = function (view, options) {
    if (options.root instanceof Array) {
        // clones the options object
        var opts = {};
        for (var key in options) opts[key] = options[key];

        // loops through the paths and tries to match the view
        var matchedView = null,
            roots = opts.root;
        for (var i=0; i<roots.length; i++) {
            opts.root = roots[i];
            matchedView = lookupProxy.call(this, view, opts);
            if (matchedView.exists) break;
        }
        return matchedView;
    }

    return lookupProxy.call(express.view, view, options)
};
```

}

You can enable the new logic by calling the function above and passing express as a parameter, and then you will be able to specify an array of views to the configuration as in the previous example:

```
var express = require('express');
enableMultipleViewFolders(express);
app.set('views', [__dirname + '/oneViewsFolder', __dirname + '/anotherViewFolder']);
```

I hope that helped you